# How to enable ActiveX controls not marked as safe using javascript code for IE, while reading XLS/XLSX local files

Tags: javascript, jquery

without enabling manually
Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page -> Internet Zone -> "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" must be “Enabled”
has to be done using javascript code.

```js
var ex;
try {
  ex = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
} catch (e) {
  alert('Your browser does not support the Activex object.\nPlease switch to Internet Explorer.');
}
var ef = ex.Workbooks.Open(oFileIn.value);
var es = ex.Worksheets(so);
var rs = parseInt(ho, 10);
var cs = parseInt(co, 10);
var ce = cs + parseInt(hco, 10) - 1;
var re = rs + parseInt(ro, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to script an ActiveX not marked as safe. You can't. This is exactly the purpose of this setting, to block execution of scripts not explicitly allowed by the user.

As a solution, you could run a powershell script in the client machine to mark the desired ActiveX as safe.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fdcc/2011/11/03/enabling-initialize-and-script-activex-controls-not-marked-as-safe-in-any-zone-can-get-you-hurt-bad/

Comment: Hi Oscar, Thank you for your reply, is there any other way to show at least popup using javascript?

Comment: @Vikky What do you mena with "show at least popup"?

Comment: I have found one link, need to check  https://mohammedatef.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/activate-activex-control-using-javascript/

Comment: I don't think that this script is gonna help. You can't bypass browser security with that. First, try to understand your problem, then try to find a solution.